Schema transformation per-request on Spring GraphQL
We are migrating from using the spring graphql kickstarter to the official Spring for GraphQL solution.
Something the kickstarter had was a Servlet that could be overridden to get the schema per request. We have a custom schema parser that gave back a schema per request depending on which client requested it.
My question is, does Spring for GraphQL have something similar?
I have read this article but that seems to add the transformation to the GraphQL Builder, which would only run at startup, versus per request.

This is currently not supported by Spring for GraphQL. You can create a new enhancement request on the project directly.
We would need a concrete use case, as well as more detailed explanation on what the behavior should be. This means that each request might be executed against a different schema?
